# WPF Take Screenshot of window in focus

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating a screenshot of a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124825/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-window)

Hi,

I want to be able to save the screenshot of only the window in focus of my WPF application(which has several open windows) instead of the entire screen. Any suggestions on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: This question is already answered, check these solutions in stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163761/c-capture-screenshot-of-active-window  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692441/printscreen-only-active-window